# Wordpress highlights custom menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation

I use "santone" theme where are 2 custom menus. In function code:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'main_nav'                      => __( 'Main Navigation', 'metcreative' ),
        'header_nav'                    => __( 'Header Navigation', 'metcreative' )
    ) );
}
```

In template:

```
$location_id = 'main_nav';
if (isset($menu_locations[ $location_id ])) {
    foreach ($menus as $menu) {
        if ($menu->term_id == $menu_locations[ $location_id ]) {
            $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu);

            foreach($menu_items as $menu_item){
                if($menu_item->menu_item_parent == 0){
                    $parentMenus[$location_id][] = $menu_item;
                }else{
                    $childMenus[$location_id][$menu_item->menu_item_parent][] = $menu_item;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I add css - current page to this menu, to highlights current page ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the classes wordpress apply to menu items. One that will be applied to currently active menu is 'current-menu-item'

so

```
.current-menu-item{
/* your css for hightlight */
}
```

Comment: No I can't because I have this : ![Screenshoot from html code][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/p2jEQ.jpg

I know that WP add default  current-menu-item  , but here I use  register_nav_menus, not wp nav menu  and here is a problem..how add in PHP function 'class' and highlight my custom menu ?